# Hide other angular directive instance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I write this simple directive:

```
app.directive('element', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: $('#template').html(),
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope) {
            $scope.close = function () {
                $scope.show = false;
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

On my page can be several elements.

```
<element></element> //element[0]. On click - hide element[1] and element[2]
<element></element> //element[1]. On click - hide element[0] and element[2]
<element></element> //element[2]. On click - hide element[1] and element[0]
```

I want that when I click on element[0](or another) all my "elements" excluding "element[0]" become hide.
How can I do it?

Comment: why don't you use ng-show and ng-hide the attribute already exist in angular

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a directive to do this. For example, you could simply use `ng-show`, with no extra code necessary.

```
<div class="elem" ng-show="!selected || selected == 1" ng-click="selected = 1">Element One</div>
<div class="elem" ng-show="!selected || selected == 2" ng-click="selected = 2">Element Two</div>
<div class="elem" ng-show="!selected || selected == 3" ng-click="selected = 3">Element Three</div>
```

This basically says to show all elements if none have been selected, but as soon as one has been selected (via clicking), only show it, hiding the others.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this plunker -     http://plnkr.co/edit/hXYgKZceRpsPtXkRN9xy?p=preview

```
app.directive('element', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope :{
          id : '@',
          text : '@'
        },
        template: '<div ng-click="hideOther()" ng-show="display">{{text}}</div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope,element) {
            $scope.display = true;
            $scope.hideOther = function () {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('elementClicked',{currentId : $scope.id ? $scope.id : ""});

            }
             $scope.$on('elementClicked', function(event,message) {

                     if($scope.id && $scope.id != message.currentId){
                          $scope.display = false;
                     }
              });
        }
    }
})
```

index.html

```
<element id="1" text="Hi1"></element>
<element id="2" text="Hi2"></element>
<element id="3" text="Hi3"></element>
```